# How to get specific data in a div with Selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, elements

Let's say this website has frequently changed data (stores). I am also only interested in certain stores from my list. How do I get all the data of the first store from the top and from my list?

I was only able to get the entire list of stores

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Bakeries')

name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers"]

storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
for i in storenames:
   rest = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
   print(i.text)
```

Comment: The target site is not accessible. It will be hard for people to deduce the DOM. Additionally, you question is not clear: "all the data from the first store from the top AND from the list?" What "top" means here? Top in the visibility or the first to appear in the DOM? They can be different.

Comment: Hello! I meant "first appeared" on the page. This website works great for me....I made this example specifically for this website. I found a solution how to make a condition for choosing a store with a specific name. Here it is: name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers"]

storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
for i in storenames:
   if ('Pat-a-Cake44') in i.text:

      print(i.text) But how do I use a list (more than one store name)?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried with ***Java + Selenium*** and it sort of worked:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cntanr'][1]//h2//span[@class='lng_cont_name']")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cntanr'][1]//p[@class='contact-info ']")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cntanr'][1]//p[@class='address-info adinfoex ']")).getText());
System.out.println();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-cn='Pat-a-Cake']//h2//span[@class='lng_cont_name']")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-cn='Pat-a-Cake']//p[@class='contact-info ']")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-cn='Pat-a-Cake']//p[@class='address-info adinfoex ']")).getText());
System.out.println();
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-cn='Chef Bakers']//h2//span[@class='lng_cont_name']")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-cn='Chef Bakers']//p[@class='contact-info ']")).getText());
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@data-cn='Chef Bakers']//p[@class='address-info adinfoex ']")).getText());
```

Although, the phone number isn't showing in the output because it's not a text from and sort of custom CSS based icon.

So maybe you can work around this in some way to get the desired output using ***Python*** by adding your logic and loops.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, i'm not good in java:((

Comment: I partially solved my issue. Here is the code: `code` name = ["Pat-a-Cake", "Chef Bakers", "Cake and Bake Emporium"]

storenames = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "store-name")
for i in storenames:
   if any(x in i.text for x in name):
      print(i.text)
   else:
      print ('NO')`code`. But, now I get a result where many are NO and these three stores are from the list. How do I get only one result - the topmost store? Thank you!

Comment: Check Python equivalent of these:   
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cntanr'][1]//h2//span[@class='lng_cont_name']")).getText()    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cntanr'][1]//p[@class='contact-info ']")).getText()    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='cntanr'][1]//p[@class='address-info adinfoex ']")).getText()